# Why Calling To Local Functions Need Relocation?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, elf

I wrote the following C code:

```
int foo(int x,int y) {
    return x;
}

int main() {
    return foo(1,2);
}
```

Then I ran:

```
gcc -c my_file.c
objdump -S my_file.o
```

and got:

Disassembly of section .text:

```
0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   7:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
   a:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   d:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   e:   c3                      retq   

000000000000000f <main>:
   f:   55                      push   %rbp
  10:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  13:   be 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%esi
  18:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  1d:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  22 <main+0x13> # Notice the zeroes here.
  22:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  23:   c3                      retq
```

But this is really strange, why the call to foo() needs to be fixed later in linking? When linking with other files the distance of foo() compared to main is constant so no need for allocation at all (We can jump to rip-distance+1 or something similar).

Please help me understand what is going on here.

Comment: It is object file not an executable. Real addresses will be assigned by the linker

Comment: @0___________ "Real addresses will be assigned by the linker" That's my question, the address is known why to wait for linker at all while we can do it Now

Comment: Plus will every call to function in object file be set to 0 waiting for it to be fixed during linking?

Comment: It could be done of course, but it is better not to, and even have the functions in different sections. If there was e.g. an unused function between foo and main, it could be eliminated, while if the branches were already fixated, the best you could do was to nil the space between the functions.  On some architectures, rearranging might also be useful to keep the number of far calls down.

Comment: _will every call to function in object file be set to 0 waiting for it to be fixed during linking_ Probably not, for functions declared `static`.

Comment: Instead of showing output from (useless) `objdump -S`, please show the output from `objdump -dr`.

Comment: @TomKarzes that is not correct. The e8 call instruction uses relative jumps, so it would be safe to insert the distance to jump here (-0x22) and skip the relocation. If you add `static` to the definition of `foo`, you'll see that this is exactly what it will do. The reason it leaves a relocation here is that another definition of `foo` might be available in a different translation unit, and that dynamic linking needs to use that one instead. So the compiler has to leave a relocation for the linker just in case.