# Why does linkage affect whether relocations are needed for relative jumps in the same section?

Tags: c, assembly, linker, x86-64, elf

In this simple program, I get a relocation in `main` for `compute`, but not for `compute2`:

```c
static int compute2()
{
    return 2;
}

int compute()
{
    return 1;
}


int main()
{
    return compute() + compute2();
}
```

I compile this with `gcc -c main.cpp` using gcc 11.2.0 on Ubuntu 21.10.

Here's what `objdump` says about `main`:

```
000000000000001e <main>:
  1e:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
  22:   55                      push   rbp
  23:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  26:   53                      push   rbx
  27:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   2c <main+0xe>    28: R_X86_64_PLT32  compute()-0x4
  2c:   89 c3                   mov    ebx,eax
  2e:   e8 cd ff ff ff          call   0 <compute2()>
  33:   01 d8                   add    eax,ebx
  35:   48 8b 5d f8             mov    rbx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  39:   c9                      leave  
  3a:   c3                      ret
```

As you can see, for the call to `compute2` (internal linkage) there is a relative jump with no relocation. But for the call to `compute` (external linkage) there is a relocation, even if all three functions are in the same section in the same object file.

Why is that relocation needed? I thought the linker would never split up a section, so no matter where this section gets loaded, relative addresses should still be the same? Why does linkage seemingly affect this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68832394/static-function-vs-non-static-in-static-linking) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68824579/why-calling-to-local-functions-need-relocation) are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this behavior is implemented to enable *symbol interposition* – by exposing the `compute` call as a relocatable opcode, you can run your code like

```
> LD_PRELOAD=custom_compute.so ./main
```

and your `compute` call will be relocated to a custom `compute` function defined in the `.so`.

---

This functionality is disabled for static functions like `compute2` - which are internally linked and shouldn't be available for symbol interposition.

---

As mentioned in comments, this behavior is not just for `LD_PRELOAD` but is more generally relevant for shared libraries - for instance, in this example, if two shared libraries were to be loaded, both defining `compute` - the second library's call to `compute` would be relocated to the first library's function.

Comment: Right, that sounds probable indeed! Then this relocation will be kept through the linking stage as a load time relocation which can be overridden by the dynamic linker if you use `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: On what do you base this belief? Have you tested it?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Not sure how to test this - but in one of the duplicates you posted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68832394/static-function-vs-non-static-in-static-linking), the only (non-accepted) answer mentions an interesting observation - the answerer was able to replicate the behavior in Linux but not in Windows. This would strengthen the theory, given that `LD_PRELOAD` is a non-Windows mechanism (and Windows' hotpatching works entirely differently from how `LD_PRELOAD` works).

Comment: @DanielKleinstein: You would test it by building a `.so` with one implementation of `compute`, say one that prints “library version”, building a program with another implementation of `compute`, say one that prints “program version”, and running the program with the command you show. I would do it, but I do not have GCC or a Linux system handy.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Barring bugs in my Linux distro, I'm sure the test you describe will work because it's just testing if `LD_PRELOAD` works. What I'm not sure how to test is that this is the explicit rationale for the relocatable opcode, for completeness we'd probably need to delve into GCC source code.. but as I mentioned - I think the answer in the question you linked provides fairly strong evidence that this is the rationale.

Comment: Re “I'm sure”: Have you tested it?

Comment: I feel no more need to run that test than I feel the need to compile `printf("Hello, world");` and see that it really prints "Hello, world" to console. i.e. if it doesn't work then I have much bigger issues on my machine :)

Comment: The term for this mechanism is “symbol interposition” and it's not just there for `LD_PRELOAD` but also for shared libraries in general.

Comment: Good point fuz. Imagine that this code goes in a static library. Then someone links against that static library, but also against a dynamic library which provides the same symbol. I believe if you link to the shared library first and then the static library, the one in the dynamic one is actually supposed to be called.

Comment: @DanielKleinstein If multiple shared libraries provide the same symbol, there's an order that decides which library's symbol is used.  This symbol is then also used for other libraries using the symbol.  This is to emulate the effects of static linking with respect to linker operand order.

Comment: @fuz Thanks! I expanded my answer for completeness.

Comment: As a side note - this is consistent with the observed behavior that the relocatable opcode isn't replicated in Windows, because Windows linking works entirely differently and only explicitly marked functions are exported from DLLs.

Comment: I tested this on Ubuntu 20.04 and it didn't work.  I get the value from the function defined in the main.cpp file, with or without LD_PRELOAD in effect.  (I had to add `-fPIC` to get it to call `compute()` through the PLT, and it still didn't get the interposed version.)

Comment: @NateEldredge This only effects shared libraries, not the main program.  Functions defined in the main program cannot be overridden like this.

Comment: @NateEldredge You have to move the `compute` function from the code to a separate library and add that library to the compilation of OP's code. What would happen without `LD_PRELOAD` is that the compute function would be linked from that shared library - with `LD_PRELOAD` it's linked from the injected library - the important point (with regards to this question) being that it's done with the relocatable opcode.

Comment: Per Nate Eldrege’s comment above, your claim has been tested and been found to be false. This answer is wrong. Refusing to test code is bad engineering.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Both fuz and me explained the change Nate had to do - as I explained, the test you proposed is not a relevant test at all but just a sanity check that `LD_PRELOAD` works as documented. The answer is not wrong, but downvote as you please.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that a *relocation* is needed per se, it's that the compiler chooses to do indirection through the *PLT* (because of possible **symbol interposition**, or in case the main executable or an earlier shared lib define the symbol). Note the relocation type `R_X86_64_PLT32`.

If you look at the compiler's asm output (not disassembly of the .o), you'd see `call compute@plt`.

A `static` function definitely always uses the definition in the same translation unit, but other definitions of global symbols can take precedence.

---

**This should only be happening for `-fPIC`**, not for building the main executable itself (`-fPIE` is on by default in most modern distros), for symbols defined in the same .c (translation unit).

https://godbolt.org/z/qYYWsYf6a
shows GCC `-fPIE` still using `call    compute`.  Apparently Ubuntu enables some other options that make this different?  (Godbolt's gcc doesn't enable-by-default several things that most distros do, so you need some options to match how GCC is configured on Ubuntu.  `-fstack-protector-strong` isn't relevant, and IDK what else would be.)

Note that when linking an executable (not a shared lib), the call should get "relaxed" to a direct call that doesn't go through the PLT.  So it's ok for GCC to emit all calls as `call foo@plt`.

If you were using `-fno-plt` as well, calls would be emitted as `call *foo@gotplt(%rip)`, which takes 6 bytes, so relaxing it to a direct 5-byte call rel32 needs a byte of filler; ld uses a meaningless address-size prefix.  (See my answer on [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126328/cant-call-c-standard-library-function-on-64-bit-linux-from-assembly-yasm-code/52131094#52131094) for an example.)

---

If you don't want this PLT indirection in the first place, you can set ELF visibility = hidden for that symbol.  This is a really good idea when making a shared library, since in that case the linker won't be able to relax all the indirection through the PLT for internal calls to functions you don't intend to allow symbol-interposition for.

You can use `-fvisibility=hidden` to make that the default for all prototypes, so calls will use `call rel32`, not indirect through the PLT (or GOT with `-fno-plt`).  Then for any function or variable a shared library does want to export, use `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`

For your case, **`-fvisibility=hidden` may solve the problem you're having**, with GCC unnecessarily indirecting even though you're not building code that can go into a shared library (with `-fPIC`).

See also

- https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility
- [How to use the __attribute__((visibility("default")))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719364/how-to-use-the-attribute-visibilitydefault)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472660/what-are-difference-between-the-elf-symbol-visibility-levels
- [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126328/cant-call-c-standard-library-function-on-64-bit-linux-from-assembly-yasm-code/52131094#52131094) (link-time relaxation example when linking an executable rather than a shared lib.)
- [Sorry state of dynamic libraries on Linux](https://web.archive.org/web/20171111043629/http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/) on Thiago Macieira's blog, from 2012.  (Before `-fno-plt` existed; so at least that idea has been implemented, and is now the default for some distros binary packages, like Arch GNU/Linux.)